# thread.join() Почему потоки вызываются в случайном порядке? С++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Пытаюсь разобраться в многопоточности и mutex. По задумке сначала должен выполниться thread Calc(Stream), после его окончания должен выполниться thread Draw(DrawStream). Но, потоки при каждом запуске программы выполняются в разном порядке. Я пытался менять местами

```
    Calc.join();
    Draw.join();
```

Но это никак не помогло. Можете обьяснить в чем причина такого поведения программы?

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

float pointsX[6000] , pointsY[6000];
std::mutex _mutex;

DWORD WINAPI Stream() {
    _mutex.lock();
    printf("Запуск первого потока\n");
    int i = 0;
    float h = M_PI / 180, x, y, a = 30, r = 30;
    float f = -3;
    while (f <= 3) {
        x = a + r * cos(f);
        y = a * sin(f) / cos(f) + r * sin(f);
        pointsX[i] = x;
        pointsY[i] = y;
        printf("x = %f     y = %f\n", x, y);
        i++;
        f += h;
    }
    printf("Окончание первого потока\n");;
    _mutex.unlock();
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI DrawStream() {
    _mutex.lock();
    printf("Запуск второго потока\n");
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    int i = 0;;
    Sleep(100);
    while (pointsX[i+1] != NULL) {
        SetPixel(hdc, 300 + pointsX[i], 50 + pointsY[i], RGB(255, 255, 255));
        i++;
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    printf("Окончание второго потока\n");
    _mutex.unlock();
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    thread Calc(Stream);
    thread Draw(DrawStream);
    Calc.join();
    Draw.join();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну так окончание потока будет только после `Calc.join();`, тогда и надо вызывать `thread Draw(DrawStream);`, а если одно выполняется после другого, то мьютекс тут не нужен.

Comment: @user7860670 но тогда какой смысл греть камень форками на поток? xD

Comment: @Andrey Никакого, но вдруг человек просто экспериментирует...

Comment: @user7860670 ну тогда ему надо посоветовать std::async(std::launch::deferred, ....)

Comment: *"Это многопоточность, сынок"* - нет никакой гарантии, кто и как пойдет первым. Нужна строгая последовательность - ставьте, например, счетчик и смотрите его значение (которое должен увеличить после отработки первый поток). Но вообще-то если многопоточность полагается на последовательность выполнения потоков - это уже не многопоточность...

Comment: @Andrey Просто пытаюсь разобраться в использовании mutex, можете подсказать в какой ситуации есть смысл его использовать? Как я понял если есть .join() , то mutex вообще не нужен, а я хочу написать код где именно mutex будет отвечать за последовательность выполнения потоков

Comment: @Zoom, мьютекс лочить необходимо перед тем как вы будете **писать/читать** в/из ресурса который общий для всех потоков. А то что вы делаете это просто бессмыслица.

Comment: @Zoom https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaF2dADZ-Y0 первое  что нашел на youtube

Comment: @ヒミコ Ну, к примеру в первом потоке в цикле я записываю данные в массив, из которого потом эти данные читает второй поток. Получается я должен залочить цикл, в котором пишутся данные в первом потоке, и цикл в котором читаются данные во втором потоке?

Comment: join() - ожидание завершения потока, а не его запуск. Поток начинает свою работу сразу после объявления.

Comment: @Zoom В последнем примере, второй поток уже может что то делать в то время, когда первый записал только половину массива ? Если да - то мутекс не на весь цикл, а не время работы с массивом, даже не с самим массивом, а с переменными обозначающими сколько элементов уже в него записано, т.е. сколько может уже обрабатывать второй поток (хотя и это с натяжкой, вот если первый поток будет периодически писать опять в начало массива, когда второй его уже обработал, вот тогда там мутексы точно будут нужны)